# How to track an alias definition in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

This is an `alias` defined in my Linux shell:

```
$ alias vi
alias vi='vim'
```

This alias is so stupid that I want to delete it definitely.

Is there a command to find where `alias vi='vim'` might have been defined? Something like Vim's `:verbose [option]?`?

---

**Update:**

After hours of search, I found that `alias vi=vim` is located in `/etc/profile.d/vim.sh`, which is sourced by `/etc/bashrc`, which is sourced by `.etc/.bashrc`, which is sourced by `~/.bash_profile`. Such a long journey!

Though I have located `alias vi=vim`, There is still a question:

**Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a way that answer these question: Is alias defined through the command line, a script file, or something else? If defined in a script file, which file it is?**

The method used above is "brute-force search". There maybe a dozen files that sourced by `~/.bash_profile`. It is so inefficient that it spent me hours to debug.

Comment: hmmm... is the command you are looking for *not* `alias` then? oh wait, i see - you're talking about in the text editor. i think you want either `: abbrev` or `: map`. no - that's not it either. you want to know where it was *defined*? you could try `grep -l 'alias vi' ~/.*` to start.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, I want to know where `alias vi='vim'` locate. I want to delete that statement. That alias is really terrible.

Comment: hahahaha!!! do the `grep` - it's almost definitely in one of your dot files in `$HOME` - probably some `~/.shellrc` or `~/.profile` or `~/.shenv` or something like that. the `grep` will spit out the file name. you could do: `grep -n 'alias vi' ~/.* /dev/null` to ensure you get the whole matched line and the filenames and the line numbers for wherever it is matched.

Comment: @mikeserv I have tried `grep` my home directory, but noting print. And I don't want to grep root directory, that is awkard!

Comment: true. ok, well, there's `/etc` possibly in `profile` - though that would be weird - or `bash/bashrc` or `zsh/zshrc` or something. another way is to do: `"$0" -vx` to get a printout of all of the commands read in when a new shell starts.

Comment: sorry about the tag... haha.

Comment: By the way which shell are you using? (`echo $SHELL`)

Comment: @Pandya bash shell

Comment: @FengYu And alias isn't defined at `.bashrc` , `.bash_aliases` or at `.bash_profile` right?

Comment: I am not sure that substitution `vi` <-- `vim` have done via **alias**. In deb-distro such operation is provided via **update-alternatives**

Comment: Please execute `type -a vi` to find out if there is an alias defined for vi.